# Fill array bidimensional without columns

Tags: java, arrays

how Can I fill an array bidimensional without a specific number of columns?

```
private Animals[] animals;
    private Animals[][] matrizAnimal;
    private final int MAX_ANIMALS = 20;
    private int numAnimals;

    CatalogueAnimals()
    {
        animals = new Animals[MAX_ANIMALS];
        numAnimals = 4;

        matrizAnimal = new Animals [2][];

        animals[0] = new Dog("Pipi", 10);
        animals[1] = new Cat("mimi", 4);
        animals[2] = new Cat("jerry", 5);
        animals[3] = new Cat("josh", 9);

    }

public void fillArrayBi()
    {

        int i=0;

        do{
                for (int col=0; col<matrizAnimal.length; col++)
                {

                        if (animals[i] instanceof Dog)
                        {
                            matrizAnimal[0][col] = animals[i];
                        }
                            else if (animals[i] instanceof Cat)
                        {
                            matrizAnimal[1][col] = animals[i];

                        }   
                    i++;
                }
        }while(i<numAnimals);


        }
```

I'm trying to fill the array. The first row contains 'Dogs' and the second row contains 'Cats'.

Thanks

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand your question... What exactly do you want to achieve in the context of your code??? Are you getting an error???

Comment: What you are trying to do is done using dynamic arrays, and in java this is done using `ArrayList` or other `Collection` types. You should check them out

Comment: I try to call fillArray method, and main give me a Exception (NullPointerException)

Comment: How did you try to use that method? I assume you want to fill the second dimension but as I said in my answer: I can't see where you're creating the elements of the first dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int col=0; col<matrizAnimal.length; col++)
{
  if (animals[i] instanceof Dog)
  {
    matrizAnimal[0][col] = animals[i];
  }
  ...
}
```

This won't work due to a number of reasons:

- `col` is bounded by the first dimension of `matrizAnimal` which is 2, thus it is somewhat risky to apply the value to the second dimension
- you created `matrizAnimal` but I can't see any code where you initialize the elements, hence `matrizAnimal[0][col]` will result in a NullPointerException because the element at index 0 doesn't exist yet

If I understand your question correctly you want to create the 2nd dimension of `matrizAnimal` with a length calculated at runtime.

For that you'd have two options:

1. If you know the length when creating the second dimension, you can pass that directly to the construction call:

   `int lengthOfRow = 4;
   matrizAnimal[0] = new Animals[lengthOfRow];`
2. If the length depends on the elements in that second dimension array you could use a list, fill that and finally convert it to an array:

   `List<Animals> list = ...;
   //fill list
   matrizAnimal[0] = list.toArray(new Animals[list.size()]);`

**Edit**:

To clarify on multi-dimensional arrays: arrays can only be one-dimensional but can contain other arrays. Hence a "multi-dimensional" array is actually an array containing arrays etc. In contrast to other languages like C++ the entire array is *not* laid out in contiguous memory.

Comment: I fixed this error with the first option.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

In `Java` arrays **need size to be declared**, so you must know the number of columns when creating the array. I would make this approach in a different way using [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

You can use 2 `ArrayList`, or if you want only one object, a `Map`:

Create and initialize `Map`

```
Map<String, List<Animals>> animalsMap = new HashMap<String, List<Animals>>();
```

Then,

```
if (animals[i] instanceof Dog)
{
    if (animalsMap.get("Dog") != null)
    {
        animalsMap.put("Dog", animalsMap.get("Dog").add(animals[i]));
    } else {
        List<Animal> a = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        a.add(animals[i]);
        animalsMap.put("Dog", a);
    }
}
else if (animals[i] instanceof Cat)
{
    if (animalsMap.get("Dog") != null)
    {
        animalsMap.put("Cat", animalsMap.get("Dog").add(animals[i]));
    } else {
        List<Animal> a = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        a.add(animals[i]);
        animalsMap.put("Cat", a);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about this, but I needed realize this with array.

Comment: so, when finished, get the max list size, create 2d array according `[2][maxSize]` and use `list.toArray`